# Querying two different tables without duplicates

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if there is a way to get a query without duplicates. I have looked at other examples but cannot get it to work. First I will show the tables.

```
ORDERS Table
id   status. company   delivery_date   drivers_id
27   24      MSC       2020-08-24      3
28   24      MSC       2020-08-24      4

DRIVERS Table
drivers_id.   drivers_name
3             Mark
4             Dan

TIME_STAMPS Table
id  order_id  time_stamp   event
2   27        2020-08-03   SOLD
3   27        2020-08-05   PRODUCTION
```

My query works fine if I do not add the time_stamp table. I want to get all the orders on specific delivery date and find if there is a SOLD timestamp in the time_stamp table. If I query like this I get multiple records. I know there is UNION and IF statements but I cannot get them to work.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `orders`
        LEFT JOIN
    `drivers` ON `orders`.`driver_id` = `drivers`.`driver_id`
        LEFT JOIN
    `time_stamps` ON `time_stamps`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id`
WHERE
    status = 24
        AND `orders`.`company` = 'MSC'
        AND `delivery_date` = '2020-08-21'
```

Comment: Have you tried `WHERE time_stamps.event = "SOLD"`?

Comment: If I did that then how would I get results from the orders table that did not have a SOLD record in the time_stamps table?

Comment: According to your question text (specifically where you said "I want to get all the orders on specific delivery date and find if there is a SOLD timestamp in the time_stamp table."), the results in the orders table that don't have a corresponding "SOLD" record in the time_stamps table are irrelevant to this query. Is that not what you had in mind?

Comment: Please provide your desired result for someone can help you.

Comment: Are the timestamps in the table time_stamps always different, can it be that production and sold are on the same day? Then you need an order for event so that it can be determined what row to show? Till now we have only the date to sort it

Comment: and which version of mysql are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a flag for sold or not for all orders on specific delivery date, If that is the case you can write a query as

```
SELECT o.id,
  o.status,
  o.company,
  o.delivery_date,
  d.drivers_name,
  coalesce(sum(t.event = 'SOLD'),0) is_sold
FROM `orders` o
LEFT JOIN `drivers` d ON o.`driver_id` = d.id
LEFT JOIN `time_stamps` t ON t.`order_id` = o.`id`
WHERE o.status = 24
    AND o.`company` = 'MSC'
    AND o.`delivery_date` = '2020-08-21'
GROUP BY o.id,
  o.status,
  o.company,
  o.delivery_date,
  d.drivers_name
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/533916/4)